# Flexslider hide bullets below slideshow

Tags: navigation, flexslider

I am using a very basic slider and I have 2 questions:

1. I do not seem to find a property that hides the default button controls below the slideshow?
   I wish to have only the prev/next controls on hovering.
2. If I cannot have option 1, will making my own controls hide the defaults?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li> <img src="http://www.xx.com/1.jpg" alt="" /> </li>
<li> <img src="http://www.xx.com/2.jpg" alt="" /> </li>
<li> <img src="http://www.xx.com/3.jpg" alt="" /> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 21):

You should pass "controlNav: false" to flexslider():

```
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    controlNav: false
  });
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        controlNav: false
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: please explain what you did

Answer (score 0):

flex-next :

```
$('#article-slider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false,
  animationLoop: false,
  slideshow: false,
  sync: "#article-carousel",
  rtl: true,
  start: function(slider) {
    $('body').removeClass('loading');
  }
});
```

Comment: Please provide explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

I have used the script at the bottom (with the 0) in the Custom CSS box and it works for PC but not for mobile slider to view on a phone

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).